# Toolbar back button does not close current Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have an activity that loads a Fragment onCreate. And I have a toolbar on that activity that has a button that when clicked will add a new Fragment on top of the one that got created first.

Now on that toolbar, when clicked, I want to remove the newer fragment so that it just displaces the fragment that is in the bottom (older one). I've searched and I kinda have figured it out except for one thing.

I did this so that it tries to see if the toolbar button is pressed:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent objEvent) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, objEvent);
    }


 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager mFM = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if(mFM.findFragmentByTag("NewFragment") != null){
            mFM.beginTransaction().remove(mFM.findFragmentByTag("NewFragment")).commit();
        }
    }
```

The problem is, "keyCode" is only equals to KEYCODE_BACK when you click the "hardware's back button" and not the back button of the toolbar. What it gives me is keycode 58 and not 4 (KEYCODE_BACK).

Comment: why not add an `or` statement with `keycode 58`.. something like `if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || keyCode == KeyEvent.XY)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what your looking for is the `NavigationListener` for the `Toolbar` Widget:

```
mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

but if your using a Theme with an `ActionBar` and setting a supportActionBar then do something :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question whether you're asking a Fragment management question (FragmentTransaction remove vs. replace), or a Toolbar button question.  I assume the latter...

An Android Toolbar or ActionBar should have actions handled using:

```
@Override
public Boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
 switch (item.getItemId())
 {
  case MY_BACK_BUTTON:
    myBackPressedHandler();
    return (true);
 }
 return (false);
}
```

this assumes that your Back button is added as a MenuItem and was given an ID of MY_BACK_BUTTON.

For a Toolbar, you can use a MenuItemClickListener to handle the click events:

```
mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(MenuItem menuItem)
{
 @Override
 public Boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem)
 {
  // call onOptionsItemSelected, or handle the click here directly
  return (thisFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem));
 }
});
```

If you're referring to the "Up" button on the Toolbar/ActionBar, i.e. setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true), this will have a getItemId() of android.R.id.home and can be handled in a similar fashion:

```
case android.R.id.home:
  myBackPressedHandler();
  return (true);
```